# AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'output_masks' in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I want to add a `Dropout` layer in my `CNN` model as shown below(highlighted in yellow):

```
inputs_1 = keras.Input(shape=(10081,1))

layer1 = Conv1D(64,14)(inputs_1)
layer2 = layers.MaxPool1D(5)(layer1)
layer3 = Conv1D(64, 14)(layer2)   
layer4 = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(layer3)

inputs_2 = keras.Input(shape=(84,))             
layer5 = layers.concatenate([layer4, inputs_2])
layer6 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(layer5)
```

> layer6.add(Dropout(0.25))(masked)

```
layer7 = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(layer6)

model_2 = keras.models.Model(inputs = [inputs_1, inputs_2], output = [layer7])
model_2.summary()
```

and it returned

> AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'output_masks'

I guess it might be that I used `Keras` and `tf.keras` but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the below code. As you are using keras functional API. You should be adding the dropout layer also this manner itself by giving the input and output

```
layer6=Dropout(0.25)(layer6)
```

In the above line I have made layer6 as input of the dropout layer and its results are saved to the same layer6. The layer6.add() should be used when you are using keras sequential API and not to be used for functional API.

The full updated code given below..

```
inputs_1 = keras.Input(shape=(10081,1))

layer1 = Conv1D(64,14)(inputs_1)
layer2 = layers.MaxPool1D(5)(layer1)
layer3 = Conv1D(64, 14)(layer2)   
layer4 = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(layer3)

inputs_2 = keras.Input(shape=(84,))             
layer5 = layers.concatenate([layer4, inputs_2])
layer6 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(layer5)
layer6=Dropout(0.25)(layer6)

layer7 = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(layer6)

model_2 = keras.models.Model(inputs = [inputs_1, inputs_2], output = [layer7])
model_2.summary()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! With this line of code will I erase the previous `layer 6`(ie. `layer6 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(layer5)`) given that they share the same name?

Comment: you can give differen names if you want the output of level 6 somewhere else in the code

Comment: For the normal cases no issues occur if you use the same name because laye6 likely would not be used anywhere in the code after that